# ¿How can I make a copy of a SpreadSheet and name it after a Cell?

Tags: google-apps-script

Im in an active SpreadSheet and trying to make a copy of another inactive SpreadSheet and trying to name it after a cell from the active SpreadSheet.

This is what im doing so far, but it gives me the following error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRange' of null. Can some one help me with this?

````
var originSS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var originSheet = originSS.getSheetByName("Sheet 1");
var newName = originSheet.getRange("B2").getDisplayValue();

var templateID = ("1TpbQjOUszz3jJlKun0WxJAyL1X93xWK2AG29B_Pv5ko");
var newSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(templateID).copy(newName);
}```
````

Answer (score 2):

Your code seems fine.

The error you're getting is because on line 2 you're getting a sheet that doesn't exist.

Just make sure there is a sheet named **"Sheet 1"**.